# Text input inside radio button group loses focus in Firefox when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, input

I'm having a problem in Firefox where if you click the `<input type="text">` in Firefox, the focus is diverted immediately to the Radio button sibling.

The behavior works as intended in Chrome. Do I need extra Javascript to fix this up?

[Here's the JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hgS3j/2/)

Answer (score 6):

Seems like Firefox is actually doing the correct thing according to the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element):

> If the for attribute is not specified, but the label element has a
>   labelable element descendant, then the first such descendant in tree
>   order is the label element's labeled control.

Your label is wrapping two input elements, so when you click in the text box, the radio (the first such descendant in tree order) receives focus.

Results will vary depending on how the browser has implement this rule, so to ensure cross-browser results yes, you'd need JavaScript to step in.

Answer (score 6):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label):

> **Permitted content:** Phrasing content, but no descendant label elements.
>   No labelable elements other than the labeled control are allowed.

Basically, putting two inputs within a label is not valid markup. Change your html markup so that the label only wraps the radio input (and any text label)...

```
<label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="requestfor" id="optionsRadios2" value="someoneelse" />
    Behalf of
</label>      
<input type="text" name="behalfof" id="behalfid"/>
```

...and then use javascript (or in my lazy case, jQuery) to select the radio:

```
$('#behalfid').click(function(){
    $('#optionsRadios2').trigger('click');
});
```

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2D7fM/).

Answer (score 0):

Did some digging around and found this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p8kvQ/) with a jQuery solution. 
Firing `trigger.click();`on radio input will select it when clicking on the textbox.

Comment: Note that this solution doesn't wrap the input in a label tag like the fiddle in the original question. Therefore you cannot click the text "Other:" to select the radio button for example.